# Flash "visible" issue

Tags: apache-flex, flash, visible

I'm writing a tool in Flex that lets me design composite sprites using layered bitmaps and then "bake" them into a low overhead single bitmapData. I've discovered a strange behavior I can't explain: toggling the "visible" property of my layers works twice for each layer (i.e., I can turn it off, then on again) and then never again for that layer-- the layer stays visible from that point on.

If I override "set visible" on the layer as such:

```
override public function set visible(value:Boolean):void
    {           
        if(value == false) this.alpha = 0;
        else {this.alpha = 1;}
    }
```

The problem goes away and I can toggle "visibility" as much as I want.  Any ideas what might be causing this?

**Edit:**

Here is the code that makes the call:

```
private function onVisibleChange():void
{
            _layer.visible = layerVisible.selected;
            changed();
}
```

The changed() method "bakes" the bitmap:

```
public function getBaked():BitmapData
    {
        var w:int = _composite.width + (_atmosphereOuterBlur * 2);
        var h:int = _composite.height + (_atmosphereOuterBlur * 2);
        var bmpData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w,h,true,0x00000000);
        var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
        var bounds:Rectangle = this.getBounds(this);
        matrix.translate(w/2,h/2);
        bmpData.draw(this,matrix,null,null,new Rectangle(0,0,w,h),true);
        return bmpData;
    }
```

Incidentally, while the layer is still visible, using the Flex debugger I can verify that the layer's visible value is "false".

Comment: Please also show the code you are using to toggle the visibility that's causing you issue.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a frame between setting `visible` and calling `changed()`.  Use the `invalidateProperties()/commitProperties()` model.

```
private bool _isChanged = false;
private function onVisibleChange():void
{
            _layer.visible = layerVisible.selected;
            _isChanged = true;
            invalidateProperties();
}

protected override function commitProperties():void {
    super.commitProperties();

    if (_isChanged) {
        _isChanged = false;
        changed();
    }
}
```